# What is the difference between TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA and AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA data type in Google Fit Android Api?

Tags: google-api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

The Google Fit API describes two of these data types of the Sensor API. However both seem to be returning the same data. Can anyone explain the difference?

Answer (score 0):

TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA:
    In the com.google.step_count.delta data type, each data point represents the number of steps taken since the last reading.

AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA: 
    Aggregate number of steps during a time interval.

You can see more here:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA to retrieve the daily total steps.
This can be useful if you require step data for use in areas where you are unable to show the permissions panel (for example, Android Wear watch faces).

AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA aggregate number of steps during a time interval. This data type is equivalent to the one used for non-aggregated data.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Setting a start and end date using a range of 1 week before this moment.
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = new Date();
cal.setTime(now);
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
Log.i(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        // The data request can specify multiple data types to return, effectively
        // combining multiple data queries into one call.
        // In this example, it's very unlikely that the request is for several hundred
        // datapoints each consisting of a few steps and a timestamp.  The more likely
        // scenario is wanting to see how many steps were walked per day, for 7 days.
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        // Analogous to a "Group By" in SQL, defines how data should be aggregated.
        // bucketByTime allows for a time span, whereas bucketBySession would allow
        // bucketing by "sessions", which would need to be defined in code.
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();
```